# Update dependency property when child property has been updated

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a class inheriting canvas with the following dependency property

```
public class StorageCanvas : Canvas
{
 public readonly static DependencyProperty StorageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Storage",
  typeof(Polygon),
  typeof(StorageCanvas));

 public Polygon Storage
 {
  get { return (Polygon) GetValue(StorageProperty); }
  set { SetValue(StorageProperty, value); }
 }
}
```

Can I somehow make the dependency property "update" when the `Storage` polygon `Points` has been altered/updated, instead of requiring the polygon to be replaced with a new instance?

Comment: What do you mean by update? Redraw? Reevaluate? Relayout? Who is changing the Storage. It wouldn't be wise to just blindly update everytime a property changes. But you can trigger that for yourself with the Invalidate methods, like InvalidateVisual. Also you can change the meta data of properties to automaticaly call the Invalidate functions if they are changed, which would not work for your Storage, because it works by calling the setter.

Comment: I think, you can use dependency property `Callbacks` and `Validation`. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @dowhilefor I want to redraw the polygon on the Canvas whenever the polygons `Points` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `Polygon.Points` is a [PointCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection.aspx), so you could just subscribe to the `Changed` event of it and then call `InvalidateVisual()` as suggested by @dowhilefor

```
public class StorageCanvas : Canvas {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty StorageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Storage",
    typeof(Polygon),
    typeof(StorageCanvas),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

  public Polygon Storage {
    get {
      return (Polygon)GetValue(StorageProperty);
    }
    set {
      SetValue(StorageProperty, value);
    }
  }

  private static void PropertyChangedCallback(
    DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
    var currentStorageCanvas = dependencyObject as StorageCanvas;
    if (currentStorageCanvas == null)
      return;
    var oldPolygon = args.OldValue as Polygon;
    if (oldPolygon != null)
      oldPolygon.Points.Changed -= currentStorageCanvas.PointsOnChanged;
    var newPolygon = args.NewValue as Polygon;
    if (newPolygon == null)
      return;
    newPolygon.Points.Changed += currentStorageCanvas.PointsOnChanged;

    // Just adding the following to test if updates are fine.
    currentStorageCanvas.Children.Clear();
    currentStorageCanvas.Children.Add(newPolygon);
  }

  private void PointsOnChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
    InvalidateVisual();
  }
}
```

So now if any individual `Point` in `Storage` changed, without actually recreating the entire object, `InvalidateVisual()` will be fired.

The concept is just about subscribing to the `Changed` event of `PointsCollection`. Whether it's the right thing to do for you is a question you need to address yourself based on your requirements and logic.

Comment: `InvalidateVisual()` is very-heavy weight way to trigger re-draw. If the size of the control is not changing, use `AffectsRender` or during `OnRender()` add a `DrawingGroup` to the `DrawingContext`, then anytime you want you can `DrawingGroup.Open()` and change the visual.

Answer (score 0):

Register the dependency property with Affects render meta data option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.affectsrender.aspx